# Flex modulleader url, why cant it just look at the root?

Tags: apache-flex, module, loader, puremvc

We are using pureMVC multicore as the flex Framework,
When we need to load a module we use the first line "moduleEval.swf";.

It works well in local for testing.

But not on the production server which is obvioulsy online, in which case i need to put he full URL.

Is that normal ?

```
 moduleLoader.url = "moduleEval.swf";
//moduleLoader.url = "http://www.foobar.com/site_media/mymodule.swf";
```

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost always use absolute urls, without the site name. The URL base directory is wherever your root application is. So if you load a module within another app, and that module loads another or something, any relative urls are relative to the base app.

```
moduleLoader.url = "/site_media/moduleEval.swf";
```